# Generate all balanced bracket combinations

Tags: javascript, recursion

Can someone please explain how the recursion works in the following code?

The goal is to print all possible balanced parenthesis combinations up to N. For example:

```
N = 2: (()), ()()
N = 3: ((())), (()()), (())(), ()(()), ()()()
```

I don't konw how this code works it gives all the possible balanced parenthesis combinations shouldn't it only give `((()))` if `n=3`?

```js
var all = [];

function parens(left, right, str) {

  // if no more brackets can be added then add the final balanced string
  if (left === 0 && right === 0) {
    all.push(str);
  }

  // if we have a left bracket left we add it
  if (left > 0) {
    parens(left - 1, right + 1, str + "(");
  }

  // if we have a right bracket left we add it
  if (right > 0) {
    parens(left, right - 1, str + ")");
  }

}


parens(3, 0, "");
console.log(all);
```

Comment: and, i suppose this is homework?

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: @epascarello the question is : the array all[] should contain only"((()))" because this is how I understand how that parens() function works so how all[] has  "[((())), (()()), (())(), ()(()), ()()()] "??

Comment: And there is no question....

Comment: So why does it have the answer in the question? Is the code broken?

Comment: `all` wouldn't be much of an all if it only had one possibility in it...

Comment: @epascarello this code works but I don't get how

Comment: So the actual question is "Can someone please explain how the recursion works in the following code?"

Comment: @epascarello yes exactly

Comment: So edit your question and add that in so people know what you are asking.

Comment: See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You could check the call of the function with all parameters and take the level as indenting for the the protocoll of calling.

Same level denotes different calls of same function call.

> ```
> left right string
>
> 3 0 
>     2 1 (
>         1 2 ((
>             0 3 (((
>                 0 2 ((()
>                     0 1 ((())
>                         0 0 ((()))  push to result
>             1 1 (()
>                 0 2 (()(
>                     0 1 (()()
>                         0 0 (()())  push to result
>                 1 0 (())
>                     0 1 (())(
>                         0 0 (())()  push to result
>         2 0 ()
>             1 1 ()(
>                 0 2 ()((
>                     0 1 ()(()
>                         0 0 ()(())  push to result
>                 1 0 ()()
>                     0 1 ()()(
>                         0 0 ()()()  push to result
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void parenthesis(int open, int close, string brak)
{
   if (open == 0 && close == 0)
      cout<<brak;
   if (open>close)
      return;
   if (open > 0)
      parenthesis(open-1, close,brak + "(");
   if (close > 0)
      parenthesis(open, close - 1,brak + ")");
}
void printPar(int n)
{
   parenthesis(n,n,"\n");
}
int main()
{
   int n=1;
   printPar(n);
   return  0;

}
```